# Make XCode Compiler allow C++ in .m files

Tags: iphone, ios, gcc, module, titanium

How can I force the XCode compiler to allow C++ in .m files? I need it to compile C++ in .m rather than .mm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:
Select your file,
Select View in the top, then Utilities, then File Inspector.
Look at File Type and make sure it is set to Objective C++ Source.

Comment: Right Click on the file > Get Info > File Source Type

Comment: Yea, on xCode 4, as far as I can tell, there's no 'Get Info' option when right clicking.  There's a lot of things Apple messed around with  in this new version.  Oh well, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to change the file extension to `.mm`.  Since you asked about other ways, you can also add the `-x objective-c++` flag, and that will work.

Comment: This may have been the right answer as while however, I used the second and answer and it was simpler.